# How do mining nodes get the same target?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I’m currently reading “Mastering Bitcoin” and am wondering if all mining nodes in the network solve the same cryptographic puzzle(ie target in the block headers). If so, how do they get that target? Is it distributed by gossip or predetermined by the bitcoin code?

I understand that every now and then they reset the target to adjust to the computing power. If it’s determined by a formula, wouldn’t there be a potential for different mining nodes having different targets because of temporary forks?

Now, let’s say we allow them to have different targets. How do different nodes validate that the mining node didn’t make up an arbitrarily easy target so it can set next block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes calculate the target based on the previous two weeks average block time. If the average block time is less than 10 min, it will raise the target, and vice-versa. Since they all use the same algorithm, there’s no need to gossip this value.

The nodes are programmed by default to accept the chain of blocks with the most total work. A solved block with a high difficulty represents a lot of work. If a miner tries to mine a block with a low difficulty, other nodes will reject that block when it is submitted and continue mining.

Let me know if that doesn’t make sense!

Comment: When a node receives a block mined by another node, will it look at the target to see that it’s exactly the same as what it computed locally? And reject it if it’s not the same? Or is there a threshold for it to reject?

Comment: It will go through a series of validations including verifying the block header, which includes the target, and make sure it matches. It will also check that the hash is at or below the target.

Comment: What about the case where there is a fork. One node will compute a target based on the past blocks in its fork while another will compute one based on its own fork. They will end up with different targets

Comment: Assuming it’s a fork caused by latency issues or two blocks mined at the same time (not a hard fork or change in the protocol), then as soon as another block is mined, that node will receive it from its peers and consider that the longest chain, and discard/invalidate its forked chain. It will not stay forked for long because all (or nearly all) of the hash power of the network is working on the longest chain and will mine a block much faster than any miners that might be on the forked chain.